# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] leads to unresolved paths in PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am currently writing a project in PHPStorm and am having issues with the editor resolving paths that are prefixed with the server's document root. An example line of this might be:

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/file.php");
```

This evaluates on the server and the page is built properly. PHPStorm however is complaining and saying "Path 'file.php' not found". I have looked into this issue and found threads online such as [this](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/290298) that outline this situation. I have tried setting the Resource Root as recommended but have had no luck. Any help or guidance as to why this is happening would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: The document root evaluates to the local drive on my laptop that I am using to debug on a local Apache instance - "/Users/Me/PhpstormProjects/MyProject". This path is also set as the Resource Root in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evaluation of `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is not supported and currently there is no way to set it up somehow.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3321 -- watch/star it to get notified on progress.

---

If you are happy to change your code a bit .. you could use this approach (**works best if you have single point entry into your app** -- e.g. all requests are routed via `index.php` or alike):

- define some constant there (e.g. `define('DIR_ROOT', __DIR__);` -- since `index.php` is usually placed in website root, it will point to the same folder as `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`)
- use it in any other file, i.e. `require_once(DIR_ROOT . "/file.php");`

---

If you are including classes this way -- maybe you should use autoloader instead (no need to do this manually)?

---

**UPDATE ( 26/05/2015 ):**

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` is supported since PhpStorm v8.0.3 and **it's resolved to the project root**, so if your web server root is located in actual subfolder (e.g. `/some/path/project_root/www`) it will not get resolved correctly.

Comment: Oh gosh that settles it I guess. It's surprising to me that DOCUMENT_ROOT is not supported in include statements but I guess they must have their reasons. I will look into autoloader. Thanks!

Comment: Well ... what is `DOCUMENT_ROOT` on IDE side .. which could be completely different to what it is on remote (actual server). Is it the same as project root .. or is it certain subfolder (very common approach). If 2nd -- currently IDE has no settings for that at all (you cannot tell IDE -- this is my website root; there are resources roots .. but they are a bit different and you have more than one of them per project). Maybe they will implement support for this is some way...

Comment: I am pretty confident they point to the same location (PHPStorm project folder) but how can I check on the IDE side to make sure? If you don't know I'll have to do more googling as a quick search turned up nothing. Thanks again.

Comment: *"I am pretty confident they point to the same location"*. You have missed the point here :) . It may point to the same location for you .. but different for me (almost on all of my projects website root is a separate subfolder -- bit better security, separation of content etc etc). And with no way of configuring it .. devs did not spent time on resolving this. In any case: at the moment IDE does not evaluate array/variable values in any way -- only constants.

Comment: Ah haha sorry I see what you're saying. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you can do to get rid of warnings -- just disable that inspection (it is not extremely useful especially if you know what files you are including) -- find it in `Preferences | Inspections | PHP`

Comment: For being the @LazyOne you are pretty helpful. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

PHP Storm 2020

**File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> (Tab) Analysis**

Field **Include Analysis** -> type your folder name here (e.g. www).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path, add the document root to the include path (`echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];`)

can also do this at runtime using http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

might also want to see : http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-include-paths.html

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: Please move this to a comment and I'll get back to you. Thanks so much!

Comment: I was originally going to comment on the original question, but apparently I need 50 rep to do that..

Comment: Ah, well in that case I'm not sure what you are supposed to do, I'll leave that up to you. Anyways I added the details you asked for in the question itself.

Comment: I tried these things and PHPStorm is still not recognizing the DOCUMENT_ROOT path unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of PHPStorm EAP fixes this bug.

[image: Screenshot working $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]]

You can get the last EAP here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program